# Как при воспроизведении аудио останавливать воспроизведение других аудио

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web-audio

На web-странице имеются аудиофайлы, которые там-же и воспроизводятся. Проблема в том, что при старте воспроизведения одновременно нескольких файлов они все воспроизводятся одновременно.
Каким образом при старте воспроизведения аудио останавливать воспроизведение других аудио?

Comment: Вчера Ваш точно такой же вопрос уже закрили.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос и по коду расскажите, где эти ссылки, как работает сейчас, какого поведения вы хотите достичь и что вы пробовали, что бы заработало как надо

Comment: "Спасибо большое! Очень полезная информация"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рискую нарваться на минусы, но что делать раз у человека горит...
Евгений, рекомендую Вам на будущее как можно более полно описывать Вашу задачу/проблему и конечно-же приводить примеры кода, т.к. без этого точно понять и подсказать Вам решение Вашей-же проблемы очень сложно, а иногда и невозможно.

Если по существу, то добавляем на каждый [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) элемент обработчик, который будет выполнятся во время воспроизведения. В самом обработчике в цикле проходим по всем другим audio элементам и ставим их на паузу:

```js
let allAudios = document.querySelectorAll( 'audio' );

allAudios.forEach( elem => {
  elem.addEventListener( 'play', function( e ) {
    allAudios.forEach( audio => {
      if( audio !== e.target ) {
        audio.pause();
        // можно удалить, если не нужно скидывать
        // текущую позицию воспроизведения на начало
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<audio controls preload="auto">
  <source src="https://github.com/rafaelreis-hotmart/Audio-Sample-files/raw/master/sample.mp3" />
</audio>
<hr />
<audio controls preload="auto">
  <source src="https://github.com/rafaelreis-hotmart/Audio-Sample-files/raw/master/sample2.mp3" />
</audio>
```

---

##### Ссылки по теме

- [HTML DOM Audio Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)
- [Интерфейс HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Comment: Насколько я помню, воспроизводимым аудио вовсе не обязательно лежать в докусенте?

Comment: @Qwertiy если Вы имеете ввиду вложенный тег source, то "да" в конкретном случае можно воспользоваться атрибутом src элемента audio, но при добавлении ogg или альтернативной ссылки на аудио при отсутствии поддержки браузером без этого не обойтись. А так, в принципе, всё это можно создать посредством API вообще без тега аудио с помощью чистого JS. Или я не правильно понял "докусент"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: И ещё пример сделал.

Answer (score 3):

Вовсе не обязательно для каждого трека создавать отдельный элемент аудио, это напрасно грузит проц, засоряет оперативку и порождает проблемы с одновременным воспроизведением треков. Достаточно использовать только один элемент аудио, а во время переключения треков задавать ему другое **src**. С одним элементом одновременность просто невозможна:

```html
<a href=# onclick="playsound('https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track1.mp3')">Track1</a><br />
<a href=# onclick="playsound('https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track3.mp3')">Track2</a>
<script>
const audio = new Audio();
function playsound(sound){
    audio.src = sound;
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: От задачи зависит, но в некоторых случаях так действительно может быть лучше.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае никак, поскольку теги с проигрываемым аудио вовсе не обязательно добавлять на страницу:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.src = 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg'
  audio.play()
})
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

Comment: Так получается, что сколько раз Вы нажмёте на кнопку, столько же раз создадите новый элемент аудио, который будет запускать воспроизведение сначала, накладываясь на предыдущее воспроизведение этой же кнопкой.

Comment: @Опан, да, и что?

Comment: Но ведь их не удаляют,  они же никуда не деваются, только накапливаются (в смысле всё новые и новые элементы аудио). Это не рентШВАбельно.

Comment: @Опан, доиграет и сборщик мусора его соберёт.